# How can I login without email and password using laravel 7 authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I need guidance on how to login without email and password. I just need to verify 2 data (rut and *card_number* from the table *DEMRE_E_posefectivas*) and login using laravel 7.x

[image]

Card Number and Rut are numbers. The table *DEMRE_E_posefectivas* has no primary key.

I know this is not correct or recommended, but I need to do it this time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and your English is perfectly fine. Please show some code, what did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: This might help: https://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-with-username-instead-of-email/